# What is the recommended way to manipulate an object inline in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a fairly robust anonymous object back from my WebApi action, and in doing so would like to keep all relevant logic together. The problem I was having is that I couldn't set properties of an object this way. My first solution was to do the following:

```
AwbNumber = new Func<JSchema>(() =>
            {
                var s = gen.Generate(typeof(string))
                s.Pattern = "^[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,32}$";
                return s;
            })()
```

But I wasn't crazy about that, so I decided to make an extension method that would allow me to manipulate an object's properties through an `Action`.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static T Manipulate<T>(this T obj, Action<T> initializer)
    {
        initializer(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

.

```
AwbNumber = gen.Generate(typeof(string)).Manipulate(
                (s) =>
                {
                    s.Pattern = "^[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,32}$";
                })
```

I'm happy with this solution, but it seems like it could be a common situation, so I was wondering if something like this already existed in .NET that I failed to find. Or is there another solution to this problem I missed entirely?

Comment: Aside from anything else, your last snippet can be shorter - just `AwbNumber = gen.Generate(typeof(string)).Manipulate(s => s.Pattern = "^[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,32}$");` No need for it to be a statement lambda.

Comment: Well, does setting the Pattern property in your first snippet not work? How is gen.Generate implemented?

Comment: Your solution seems to be the only applicable for now. C# 7 will bring us a new clause `*** with { *** }` that will help you in this case.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten `gen.Generate()` is a factory method. It is taken directly from my code, but it would be comparable to a `new JSchema()` or any other `new` call.

Comment: @Caramiriel Good point. Shouldn't be an issue for my use case, but good to keep in mind.

Comment: @Kyle Usually, if you can't modify an object property, that object is anonymous. What does the Generate method return?

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev That's looks promising. Do you have any references on that handy? It's difficult searching for "c# with"

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I am functionally able to modify the object. The issue I'm having is that I don't want to prepare my objects in one place, and then place them into an anonymous object to be returned separately. My goal is to keep the initialization of all objects inside my own anonymous object I'm creating so that it is more easily maintainable. (I'm implementing an `OPTIONS` action that describes the current resource if that use case helps).

Comment: @Kyle You can find the proposal in the Roslyn's GitHub